# Allowed to bring rucksack (28 cm x 15 cm x 55 cm) in cabin luggage?

Tags: hand-luggage, turkish-airlines, backpacks, jet-airways

[image: This is approximately 45litres rucksack bag]

Can this kind of bag be carried as cabin luggage? I'll be travelling from India to Germany mostly via JetAirways or Turkish Airlines.

JetAirways website does mention cabin luggage dimensions of 55x25x15cm. But I still want to hear experiences from other people.

Comment: Are you sure the dimensions and the picture match? Unless that woman is really, really short, the rucksack is quite a bit taller than 55 cm. Also, 55 x 28 x 15 cm means a maximum volume of 23.1 l (if the bag was strictly rectangular), while it says "50 Ltr" which I suppose means 50 l.

Comment: One of the other pictures for that bag on Amazon India actually show 65 cm height, not 55. Of course, it all depends how much you fill it. Since this is a soft bag, it really depends on the actual size once you fill it, which can probably vary quite significantly both ways. Also don't forget to count the straps (shouldn't make much of a difference unless they are padded or somewhat rigid, though).

Answer (score 4):

The bag you show is bigger than the allowed dimensions on one JetAirways, and that pretty much answers your question. ([The other answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/124373/11491) says it's within limits on Turkish Airlines, so you should be fine if you manage to get it that far.)

I've never flown with those two airlines but, since the bag looks big, there's a good chance you'll be challenged about it. If it doesn't fit in one of their luggage measuring things, you won't be allowed to bring it as carry-on. If the bag is full, it won't fit, because it's too big. If it's not full, you'll probably be able to squish it into the measuring gauge – but if it's not full, that means you don't need such a big bag, so why not use a smaller one that meets the airline's rules?

Answer (score 1):

A partial answer here.

Turkish Airlines allows cabin baggage up to [23x40x55cm](https://www.turkishairlines.com/en-gb/any-questions/what-are-the-maximum-dimensions-and-weight-restrictions-for-my-baggage/index.html), thus your rucksack has no issue.

> **What are the maximum dimensions and weight restrictions for my cabin baggage?**
>
> In Economy Class you can bring a single carry-on that must have
>   dimensions of no more than 23x40x55 cm and a maximum weight of 8 kg.
>   Business Class passengers can bring two pieces carry-ons that must
>   each have dimensions of no more than 23x40x55 cm and a maximum weight
>   of 8 kg. For more detailed information please visit our cabin baggage
>   page.

Comment: Thanks for posting that -- I've removed from my answer the guess that it wouldn't be OK on Turkish.